# Meaning of the transpose of a gradient

Tags: vectors, differentiation, notation, navier-stokes

Sometimes I encounter PDE's with a term like this

$\nabla \cdot c(\nabla \textbf{v} + (\nabla \textbf{v})^T)$

An example are the Navier-Stokes equations. Oftentimes this can be further simplified to $c\nabla^2\textbf{v}$.

I understand gradients, divergence and the Laplacian. But somehow I cannot grasp the role of this transpose. Is this only an artifact from the derivation of the equation, or is there a deeper meaning that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it helps to write out the Cartesian components of this expression:
\begin{equation}
c \sum_{k=1}^3 \partial_k  \left(\partial_k v_i + \partial_i v_k\right)
\end{equation}
where $i$ and $k$ run over $\{1, 2, 3\}$, and where
\begin{equation}
\partial_i \equiv \frac{\partial }{\partial x^i}
\end{equation}
The meaning of the transpose is that the indices on the partial derivative and the vector are switched.

Comment: Hm, yes I can see that, but I was thinking more on the physical interpretation.

I realized that the sum of a square matrix A and its transpose A^T is a symmetrical matrix. Now I am trying to make the connection, for instance in the case of the strain-rate-tensor ϵ=1/2(∇u+∇u^T), of why it needs to be symmetrical. Probably it's something very basic but since I'm away from the formal literature for a while this hasn't clicked for me yet.

Comment: @LucasVieira Are you looking for something like this? https://eng.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Civil_Engineering/Book%3A_All_Things_Flow_-_Fluid_Mechanics_for_the_Natural_Sciences_(Smyth)/17%3A_Appendix_F-_The_Cauchy_Stress_Tensor/17.03%3A_F.3_Symmetry_of_the_stress_tensor

Comment: Yes @Andrew, that is precisely what I was looking for. Many thanks!